# How to benchmark if I need a reset in each iteration?

Tags: testing, go, benchmarking

I've written a small Sudoku solver using backtracking. Now I want to benchmark the speed of this function. Here is my current code:

```
type Board struct {
    Cells [9][9]int
}

func BenchmarkBacktrack(b *testing.B) {
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        b.StopTimer()
        // prevent the modification of the orignal board
        copy := &Board{
            Cells: exampleBoard.Cells,
        }
        b.StartTimer()
        copy.Backtrack()
     }
}
```

Since `&Board` is pointer I would solve the Sudoku in the first iteration and in the next one I would backtrack a solved board. Therefore, I reset the board at the beginning of each iteration. `exampleBoard` is filled with sample values.

Is their a better way to benchmark the function without stopping and restarting the timer over and over?

And wouldn't cost the function calls a small amount of time that impacts the benchmark?

Comment: https://golang.org/pkg/testing/#B.ResetTimer ?

Comment: Thanks for your answer but to recreate the board inside the loop at the beginning of each iteration. By using ResetTimer() I would create an infinite loop since the timer be reset in each iteration and the benchmark never finishes.

Comment: So aside from your current solution, I can only think that all the test data is setup outside of the loop, i.e setup `b.N` copies which would still require the StopTimer, StartTimer but only once.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with setup b.N copies?

Comment: @miltonb `b.N` isn't a constant, it's dynamically adjusted based on the benchmark speed so that won't work.

Comment: Though you COULD precompute some suitably large number like 10000 boards and use those.

Comment: @Jsor you mean something like an array with 10000 copies of the board that will the loop will iterate trough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> And wouldn't cost the function calls a small amount of time that that impacts the benchmark?

Of course they would. So does the `for` loop, which is included in the benchmark. Plus overhead of calling `copy.Backtrack` function. But the thing is, this should be all irrelevant, unless you're benchmarking a single operation taking nanoseconds (in which case you shouldn't). Creation of an empty board is probably a trivial operation, so I wouldn't touch the timers at all. If it's not trivial, then you're doing it right – call `StopTimer`. This is exactly why it was invented:

> StopTimer stops timing a test. This can be used to pause the timer while performing **complex** initialization that you don't want to measure.

Comment: I had the same thoughts while reading the docs since the testing package doesn't offer real alternatives for my usecase.

Answer (score 1):

You could try providing a `func NewBoard([9][9]int) *Board` method, which just initializes a board from the example data. Then write a benchmark for `Backtrack()` on a new board and a separate benchmark for `NewBoard()`.

Subtracting the two numbers should give you an idea of the speed of your Backtrack method alone.

```
type Board struct {
    Cells [9][9]int
}

var scratch *Board

func NewBoard(cells [9][9]int) *Board {
    return &Board{Cells: cells}
}

func BenchmarkBacktrack(b *testing.B) {
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        scratch = NewBoard(exampleBoard.Cells)
        scratch.Backtrack()
}

func BenchmarkNewBoard(b *testing.B) {
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        scratch = NewBoard(exampleBoard.Cells)
}
```

Also note the use of `scratch` variable. Trying to create a loop local variable inside the benchmark loop could lead the compiler to optimise away the call to `NewBoard()` depending on presence/absence of side-effects. For parity, you need to use the `scratch` variable in both benchmarks.